# How can I ensure one of my variables dosen't get minified when compiling in emcc?

Tags: javascript, sql.js, emcc

So...I am modifying [sql.js.](https://sql.js.org/#/?id=example-html-file) In this project I am trying to export a function / object I created and somehow the name gets minified when I compile with `emcc`

The `Database` that `sql.js` exports does not get minified. How might I be able to modify this project such that my object name does not get modified and I can use it later?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you want to be able to access a variable you declared inside a JavaScript file from anywhere else in the browser, but it's getting minified? A quick fix would be `window.myVariable = ...` and access it like `myVariable` from anywhere.

Comment: @Bergi - yes, EMCC - https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html

Comment: @code - I tried declaring variables outside, but the compiler is very strict